# Can we copy and paste or import the test cases from one test set into another test set in test lab using ALM rest api using JAVA

Tags: java, alm

I want to import or copy paste Test cases from one test set to another test set in Test Lab using ALM rest api services on JAVA platform. can anyone help on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Of course this is possible using REST API. I hope that you have already developed the initial login part.

Afterwards you can use the "copy" action as in he REST API manual or as I can suggest follow the below steps:

1) Create a new test-set under

```
POST SERVER-ADDR/rest/domains/DOMAIN_NAME/projects/PROJECT_NAME/test-sets valid HEADER and DATA
```

2) Read out the needed information from other test-set:

```
GET SERVER-ADDR/rest/domains/DOMAIN_NAME/projects/PROJECT_NAME/test-instances/TEST-SET-ID valid HEADER
```

3) For each TEST-CASE part of test-set, then create same under test-set created at point 1).

This will create same "links" to the test-cases you wanted. You can even try to modify the xmlData or JSON you get back at point 2 and create all the links in one shot :-)

That should be more than enough in your case and quite easy to automate.
Hope this help you :-)
Have a nice day!